# Issue with Apex triggers that fire as a result of time-dependent actions

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

(Case --> Case Task; 1 Case can have Multiple Case tasks; Case task has a lookup relationship to Case)

We have a time dependent workflow on a custom object (Case Task) and action is a field update on Case Task. (e.g: Status = 'Available')

Also we have after update trigger on Case task object (which has some custom logic written). In this case one of the after update trigger functionality is to update the corresponding Case.status to 'Available' whenever the Case task is set to Available.

Within we are using a static variable (e.g: runOnceafterTrigger ) to avoid recurssive updates betweeen (Case tasks & Case objects).

The above time dependent workflow runs fine and the case task trigger is fired and Case gets updated to the correct status.

We are in the phase of regression testing and sometimes the Case task after update trigger does not fire and the case status never gets updated.

Recently I saw the below article on the considerations for time dependent workflow; where the Salesforce is saying the time dependent workflow action may run individually or in group and we should not use Apex static variables to communicate state across Apex code.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US

In our case, I believe the after update trigger is not firing for all case tasks actions because the static variable is not reset.

This issue is happening very sporadically and could not replicate it every time.

Just wondering if anyone had to deal with similar scenarios (Apex triggers that fire as a result of time-dependent actions)

Answer (score 2):

> Recently I saw the below article on the considerations for time dependent workflow; where the Salesforce is saying the time dependent workflow action may run individually or in group and we should not use Apex static variables to communicate state across Apex code.

The article you're referring to is talking about static variables that aren't bulk safe, as in if you were trying to track the state of a record and were making the assumption that the trigger only fired one record at a time. If that were the case, you'd want to use a `static list` of some kind to keep track of for example, all the id's or a map of ids compared to some value.

In your case, that's not what you're doing. Once an instance of your trigger fires in that execution context, it can't fire again. It doesn't matter how many time-dependent workflow records are fired in an execution, whether one or 300, your trigger will fire for each "batch" if you've located the static boolean in the proper location.

Now, if you've not located your boolean in the proper location, it might not work at all, fire once but not for the 2nd batch that included record #201 and above, or it could prevent other instances of the same handler class from firing in a different execution context.

I've seen the last two happen with triggers that use handler or "helper" classes. If we assume the variable is called from a Utility Class, as the code in the Handler Class executes to call the variable (or test it's value), this is where one has to be cautious. Sometimes it's best not to make the variable static. Why? Because it can impact other handler classes called from the same trigger in other execution contexts. The handler classes won't know the context, only what the current value of the static variable is because of the class that's already executing.

Its for the above reason that trigger platforms work so well, especially the ones that have a "trigger main" that directs all the flow to handler classes and also holds the static boolean variables as well. This ensures that all static variables are associated with the same execution context of that instance. When  calling handler classes from standard triggers, you don't have that same level of control that comes with having instances of abstract classes and/or interfaces.

**EDIT**

Here's something of a contrived example I tried to pared down from old code to illustrate what I'm talking about.

**Uility Class for Static Boolean Variables**

```
public class TriggerHelper {

public static Boolean isUpdte = false;
public static Boolean isInsrt = false;
public static Boolean isAftr = false;
public static boolean CtcReEntryI = false;
public static boolean CtcReEntryU = false;

}
```

**Trigger**

```
trigger Contact on Contact (after insert) {

        if(trigger.isAfter){
            TriggerHelper.isAftr = true;

            if(trigger.isInsert){       
                TriggerHelper.isInsrt = true;
                new ContactHandler(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newmap, trigger.oldmap);
            }

        }

}
```

**Trigger Handler Class**

```
public with sharing class ContactHandler {

public map<Id,Contact>newMap; 
public map<Id,Contact>oldMap; 
public map<Id,Id>cId2aId;
public list<Contact>ctcNew;
public list<Contact>ctcOld;

    public contactHandler(list<Contact> newList, list<Contact> oldList, map<ID,Contact> newMap, map<ID,Contact> oldMap){

        list<Contact>ctcNew = (newList);
        list<Contact>ctcOld = (oldList);
        newMap = (newMap);
        oldMap = (oldMap);     

        if(TriggerHelper.isInsrt && TriggerHelper.isAftr && !TriggerHelper.isUpdte){

            processCtcIndustryInsrt(ctcNew, ctcOld, newMap, oldmap);

        }

    }   

    public static void processCtcIndustryInsrt(list<Contact> newList, list<Contact> oldList, map<ID,Contact> newMap, map<ID,Contact> oldMap){

        list<Contact>ctcNew = (newList);
        list<Contact>ctcOld = (oldList);
        newMap = (newMap);
        oldMap = (oldMap);     
        map<Id,Id>cId2aId = new map<Id,Id>();

        if(TriggerHelper.isInsrt && TriggerHelper.isAftr && !TriggerHelper.CtcReEntryI && !TriggerHelper.CtcReEntryU){
            TriggerHelper.CtcReEntryI = true; 

                for(Id cid:newMap.keyset()){
                        cId2aId.put(cid,newMap.get(cid).accountid);
                }

            processRecordsToUp(cId2aId);

        }
    }

        public static void processRecordsToUp(map<Id,Id> cId2aId){  

            cId2aId = (cId2aId);

            if(!cId2aId.isEmpty()){ 

                Map<Id,Account>AcctMap = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,Industry FROM Account WHERE Id IN :cId2aId.values()]);

                list<Contact>toUp = new list<Contact>();

                for(Id cid : cId2aId.keyset()){
                    contact c = new contact(Id = cid);
                    c.Account_Industry__c = AcctMap.get(cId2aId.get(cid)).Industry;

                    toUp.add(c);
                }

                if(toUp.isEmpty() == false) update toUp;

            }   

    }

}
```

With this Handler Class as written, there will potentially be problems because of the static variables that are used if one instance of the trigger is running at the same time another instance is also firing. Do you see why?

The static variables are called from the handler class and won't be able to discern which trigger is calling them. So once `TriggerHelper.CtcReEntryI = true;` that applies to all instances of the the `ContactHandler Class` that will execute from that point forward regardless of which trigger execution context they're called from!

This is a case where using a Static variable was not a desirable solution when called from the Handler Class. Now, if it had been called from the trigger, everything would have been fine. Originally, this class contained an AfterUpdate section as well which is what caused the code to head in this direction and led to creating the problem. Because of that, control of flow needed to be done inside the class, not from the trigger. Two separate handlers with reentry booleans for each called separately from the base trigger is what was actually needed. I was emphasizing utilizing the common code instead of separating the concerns.

Comment: @user5352 N.B. the fflib Separation of Concerns library provides a [nice framework for disabling recursive trigger](https://andyinthecloud.com/2016/04/13/disabling-trigger-events-in-apex-enterprise-patterns/) if one has made the leap to this framework